# How to use dropna() in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a df with 300 columns, and I need to get drop the null values of each column in a loop using its index but I can't seem to make it work.

```
def funct_one(data):
    for i in range(300):
         #use = data.dropna(subset = data.columns[:, i])
         #use = data.dropna(subset = data.iloc[:, i])
         subset = data.columns[i]
         use = data.dropna(subset = subset)
         if len(use[i]) ...
```

This is the beginning of my function, with a few different things that I have tried. How can I subset dropna() without using the column name?

Comment: Looping over columns would work as `for column in data.columns: data[column] = data[column].dropna()`. Which could become rather messey, since you might end up with differently sized columns, which doesn't work in a single dataframe. But see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

dropna will also work on the whole dataframe, and since your `data` is 300 columns I would recommend this. Is there a reason you want to loop over everything?
as opposed to something like
`no_na = data.dropna()`

Comment: The issue is that if I do dropna() on the entire dataset I'm only left with 3 out of over 1000 rows, which isn't enough to do the calculations that I'm trying to do.

Comment: I need to do 300 regressions for each one of the columns, which is why I need the loop, in order to filter each column for NaN separately.